# how to implement a "soft barrier" in multithreaded c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have some multithreaded c++ code with the following structure:

```
do_thread_specific_work();
update_shared_variables();
//checkpoint A
do_thread_specific_work_not_modifying_shared_variables();
//checkpoint B
do_thread_specific_work_requiring_all_threads_have_updated_shared_variables();
```

What follows checkpoint B is work that could have started if all threads have reached only checkpoint A, hence my notion of a "soft barrier".

Typically multithreading libraries only provide "hard barriers" in which all threads must reach some point before any can continue. Obviously a hard barrier could be used at checkpoint B.

Using a soft barrier can lead to better execution time, especially since the work between checkpoints A and B may not be load-balanced between the threads (i.e. 1 slow thread who has reached checkpoint A but not B could be causing all the others to wait at the barrier just before checkpoint B).

I've tried using atomics to synchronize things and I know with 100% certainty that is it NOT guaranteed to work. For example using openmp syntax, before the parallel section start with:

```
shared_thread_counter = num_threads;  //known at compile time
#pragma omp flush
```

Then at checkpoint A:

```
#pragma omp atomic
shared_thread_counter--;
```

Then at checkpoint B (using polling):

```
#pragma omp flush
while (shared_thread_counter > 0) {
  usleep(1);  //can be removed, but better to limit memory bandwidth
  #pragma omp flush
}
```

I've designed some experiments in which I use an atomic to indicate that some operation before it is finished. The experiment would work with 2 threads most of the time but consistently fail when I have lots of threads (like 20 or 30). I suspect this is because of the caching structure of modern CPUs. Even if one thread updates some other value before doing the atomic decrement, it is not guaranteed to be read by another thread in that order. Consider the case when the other value is a cache miss and the atomic decrement is a cache hit.

So back to my question, how to CORRECTLY implement this "soft barrier"? Is there any built-in feature that guarantees such functionality? I'd prefer openmp but I'm familiar with most of the other common multithreading libraries.

As a workaround right now, I'm using a hard barrier at checkpoint B and I've restructured my code to make the work between checkpoint A and B automatically load-balancing between the threads (which has been rather difficult at times).

Thanks for any advice/insight :)

Comment: I'm confused about your question. If you have a hard barrier at A, then any code after A, including code after B, will only be executed after each thread has passed that barrier. What for do you need any barrier at B?

Comment: @Walter Using a hard barrier at A is functionally correct, but one may lose performance. Consider the penalty for waiting on one slow thread to get to A before allowing any thread to start on the work between A and B (since based on the structure we really don't need to wait at A).

Answer (score 2):

How about using condition variable? I'm not sure if a condition variable is provided since I'm not familiar with OpenMP.

```
int counter = 0;
condition_variable cond;

// checkpoint A
++counter;
cond.notify_all();

// checkpoint B
cond.wait_until( counter >= NUM_THREADS );
```

Before every thread reaches to checkpoint A, no thread can pass through checkpoint B.

Comment: Which libraries support condition variables? Does this guarantee no possible race condition like that of the solution with atomics which I gave?

Comment: @Jason `boost::thread` and `std::thread in C++11` and maybe `tbb`. http://ideone.com/avjlp is a rough code i just wrote. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting condition variables, however after a little research I think it cannot guarantee no possible race condition. From what I understand, the only way to avoid racing is for the worst case delay due to a cache miss (e.g. external memory access) to still be faster than then synchronizing mechanism between threads (e.g. a lock, or as you suggested condition variables). Obviously this will depend on the implementation of said synchronization constructs, hardware support and lots of other parameters. (Continued...)

Comment: Ironically, the whole point of this soft barrier was to speed up computation, but to guarantee correctness one has to use a slow synchronization construct. I think the real solution is to restructure the code so that it has better load balancing properties. Anyhow, thanks again :)